# Sympy Tensor Product wrong result

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a tensor W of size [3x2] and a tensor Tr of size [2x12]. I do

```
A = Array(Matrix([
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ])).reshape(3,3,4)

b = Array(Matrix([
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1]
    ])).reshape(3,4,1)

MatMul(A,b)
```

I believe this is done with matmul? But when I try to do it with SymPy Matmul i get the error:

`AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_base_exp'`

Comment: You need to show some working `sympy` code to make you question clear.

Comment: Read this `sympy tensor module` page more carefully,https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html#products-and-contractions.  You want a matrix product, which requires a contraction as well.  This tensor product is a generaized `outer product`, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: I have added a sample non vectorized code

Comment: `A @ b` using numpy `matmul` operator.  Is this a numpy or sympy problem?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the code to reflect the problem in Sympy. As you can see, I have a [3,3,4] tensor and a [3,4,1] tensor. I want to do a batched Matrix Multiply so i use MatMul, but i get an error

Comment: any luck? matmul works on numpy but not in Sympy? I could write it in a for loop but would really hope to make MatMul work in a tensorized way

Comment: I'm no `sympy` expert, but I don't think its `MatMul` class is at all related to the `matmul` function in `numpy`.  With all these edits, this question is moving target.

Comment: Is there a MatMul equivalent in Sympy? I do not intend to change the question further

Comment: A couple things puzzle me.  Your example arrays contain just numbers, no symbols.  Why `sympy` then?  But sticking with `sympy`, why not do the 'batching' in a loop?  'vectorizing' to avoid loops is a `numpy` concept, where there's a big difference in speed between compiled code and Python cover.  I don't think that's as significant an issue in `sympy`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's clarify the action of `matmul` in `numpy`:

```
In [8]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4); B = np.arange(8).reshape(2,4,1)       
In [9]: A@B                                                                     
Out[9]: 
array([[[ 14],
        [ 38],
        [ 62]],

       [[302],
        [390],
        [478]]])
In [10]: _.shape                                                                
Out[10]: (2, 3, 1)
```

This is doing a `dot`, or 2d matrix product, on the last 2 axes.  Batching in effect on the first axis:

```
In [11]: A[0].dot(B[0])                                                         
Out[11]: 
array([[14],
       [38],
       [62]])
```

I prefer the clarity of `einsum`, where the `i` axis carries though, `k` axis is the sum-of-products one.

```
In [12]: np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',A,B)                                          
Out[12]: 
array([[[ 14],
        [ 38],
        [ 62]],

       [[302],
        [390],
        [478]]])
```

I think the question here is whether the `sympy/tensor` module can do the same.

```
In [13]: from sympy import Array, tensorproduct, tensorcontraction              
In [14]: As = Array(A[0])                                                       
In [15]: As                                                                     
Out[15]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
In [16]: Bs = Array(B[0])                                                       
In [17]: Bs                                                                     
Out[17]: [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
In [18]: tensorproduct(As,Bs)                                                   
Out[18]: [[[[0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [1], [2], [3]], [[0], [2], [4], [6]], [[0], [3], [6], [9]]], [[[0], [4], [8], [12]], [[0], [5], [10], [15]], [[0], [6], [12], [18]], [[0], [7], [14], [21]]], [[[0], [8], [16], [24]], [[0], [9], [18], [27]], [[0], [10], [20], [30]], [[0], [11], [22], [33]]]]
In [19]: tensorcontraction(_, (1,2))                                            
Out[19]: [[14], [38], [62]]
```

So `Out[19]` matches `Out[11]`. And we could repeat this for `A[1]` etc.

And with `sympy/Matrix` class:

```
In [20]: from sympy import Matrix                                               
In [21]: Matrix(A[0])*Matrix(B[0])                                              
Out[21]: 
Matrix([
[14],
[38],
[62]])
```

Make 3d sympy `Array`:

```
In [22]: AS = Array(A)                                                          
In [23]: AS                                                                     
Out[23]: [[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]], [[12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]]
In [24]: AS.shape                                                               
Out[24]: (2, 3, 4)
In [25]: BS = Array(B)                                                          
In [26]: BS.shape                                                               
Out[26]: (2, 4, 1)
```

`tensorproduct` produces a 6d array:

```
In [28]: CS = tensorproduct(AS, BS)                                             
In [29]: CS.shape                                                               
Out[29]: (2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1)
```

remove the middle `2`:

```
In [30]: CS[:,:,:,0,:,:].shape                                                  
Out[30]: (2, 3, 4, 4, 1)
```

and do the contraction as before:

```
In [31]: tensorcontraction(CS[:,:,:,0,:,:],(2,3)).shape                         
Out[31]: (2, 3, 1)
In [32]: tensorcontraction(CS[:,:,:,0,:,:],(2,3))                               
Out[32]: [[[14], [38], [62]], [[86], [110], [134]]]
```

The first half matches `Out[9]`, but not the rest.

`matmul` was added to `numpy` in large part because it was difficult to implement the desired 'batch' operation with `np.dot` (and/or `np.tensordot`).  `np.einsum` was the only alternative that worked.

This `einsum` with a `k` contraction, contains both the `Out[9]` and `Out[32]` values:

```
In [80]: np.einsum('ijk,lkn',A,B)                                               
Out[80]: 
array([[[[ 14],
         [ 38]],

        [[ 38],
         [126]],

        [[ 62],
         [214]]],


       [[[ 86],
         [302]],

        [[110],
         [390]],

        [[134],
         [478]]]])
```

The question is, how to select the right subset.  `tensorcontraction` without indexing also produces those.  `CS[:,:,:,0,:,:]` wasn't the right way to remove the repetition.

```
In [81]: tensorcontraction(CS, (2,4))                               
Out[81]: [[[[14], [38]], [[38], [126]], [[62], [214]]], [[[86], [302]], [[110], [390]], [[134], [478]]]]

Out[81]: [[[[14], [38]], 
           [[38], [126]], 
           [[62], [214]]], 

          [[[86], [302]], 
           [[110], [390]], 
           [[134], [478]]]
         ]
```

With the `einsum` I can take a diagonal:

```
In [96]: np.einsum('ijk,lkn',A,B)[[0,1],:,[0,1],:]                              
Out[96]: 
array([[[ 14],
        [ 38],
        [ 62]],

       [[302],
        [390],
        [478]]])
```

We can do the same with another `einsum`, `np.einsum('ijim->ijm', np.einsum('ijk,lkn',A,B))`, which consolidates to the `In[12]` expression, 'ijk,ikl->ijl'.

I can do the same with the `Out[81]` object.  The `sympy.Array` apparently doesn't implement the same sort of advanced indexing as `numpy`:

```
In [108]: np.array(Out[81].tolist())[[0,1],:,[0,1],:]                           
Out[108]: 
array([[[14],
        [38],
        [62]],

       [[302],
        [390],
        [478]]], dtype=object)
```

I should have remembered that in other situations when I tried to implement `matmul` style batch products with `np.dot`, that I've had to take a diagonal like this.  In effect the `dot` is taking an outer product on the non-consolidated dimensions, and we have to throw away most of the values.

Another way to look at this is we want `np.dot(A[0], B[0])` and `np.dot(A[1], B[1])`.  But the `tesorproduct` (outer product) is also giving us `np.dot(A[0], B[1])`, and `np.dot(A[1], B[0])`.